# Theory behind Autotune/vocoder

Tags: audio, core-audio, audio-processing

I've been hunting all over the web for material about vocoder or autotune, but haven't got any satisfactory answers. Could someone in a simple way please explain how do you autotune a given sound file using a carrier sound file?
(I'm familiar with ffts, windowing, overlap etc., I just don't get the what do we do when we have the ffts of the carrier and the original sound file which has to be modulated)

EDIT: After looking around a bit more, I finally got to know exactly what I was looking for -- a channel vocoder. The way it works is, it takes two inputs, one a voice signal and the other a musical signal rich in frequency. The musical signal is modulated by the envelope of the voice signal, and the output signal sounds like the voice singing in the musical tone.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to ask this signal pricessing question over at http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might want to try Melodify SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Using a phase vocoder to adjust pitch is basically pitch estimation plus interpolation in the frequency domain.

A phase vocoder reconstruction method might resample the frequency spectrum at, potentially, a new FFT bin spacing to shift all the frequencies up or down by some ratio.  The phase vocoder algorithm additionally uses information shared between adjacent FFT frames to make sure this interpolation result can create continuous waveforms across frame boundaries.  e.g.  it adjusts the phases of the interpolation results to make sure that successive sinewave reconstructions are continuous rather than having breaks or discontinuities or phase cancellations between frames.

How much to shift the spectrum up or down is determined by pitch estimation, and calculating the ratio between the estimated pitch of the source and that of the target pitch.  Again, phase vocoders use information about any phase differences between FFT frames to help better estimate pitch. This is possible by using more a bit more global information than is available from a single local FFT frame.

Of course, this frequency and phase changing can smear out transient detail and cause various other distortions, so actual phase vocoder products may additionally do all kinds of custom (often proprietary) special case tricks to try and fix some of these problems.

Comment: So in the case where someone's singing, to get their tone to the right note, you determine the nearest note and shift. But what if I want to recreate the songify effect, where a simple voice can be turned into music taking the help of a frequency rich carrier file?

Answer (score 3):

The first step is pitch detection. There are a number of pitch detection algorithms, introduced briefly in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm
Pitch detection can be implemented in either frequency domain or time domain. Various techniques in both domains exist with various properties (latency, quality, etc.) In the F domain, it is important to realize that a naive approach is very limiting because of the time/frequency trade-off. You can get around this limitation, but it takes work.

Once you've identified the pitch, you compare it with a desired pitch and determine how much you need to actually pitch shift.

Last step is pitch shifting, which, like pitch detection, can be done in the T or F domain. The "phase vocoder" method other folks mentioned is the F domain method. T domain methods include (in increasing order of quality) OLA, SOLA and PSOLA, some of which you can read about here: http://www.scribd.com/doc/67053489/60/Synchronous-Overlap-and-Add-SOLA

Comment: In frequency domain, can pitch detection simply be detecting which "bin" or frequency index has the maximum energy? (maximum amongst the magnitude of the complex numbers at each index) Although it makes a little sense, it seems to be too easy to be true. The wiki page doesn't have any mention of this.

Comment: Two practical problems with that: 1. for complex sounds, the fundamental frequency may not be the strongest, so you need to look at the relationships between the peaks. And 2. the bin size is usually too large to get an accurate approximation, so you need to take phase into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do an FFT, then in the frequency domain you move the signals to the nearest perfect semitone pitch.